# Is it possible to get from a propositional formula a CNF with clause (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ ¬C), if formula doesn't have negations in it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

If i have a propositional formula consisting of conjunctions, disjunctions and implications and no negations of three literals $A, B, C$, is it possible to get a CNF from that formula which include this clause:

$(\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C)$

How could i prove that? Is it possible to get an example which would prove that its possible? If yes, what is the algorithm to get that example (and example itself)?

Comment: Are other literals besides $A,B,C$ allowed?  Are negations of the other literals allowed?

Comment: @GEdgar no, only $A,B,C$

Comment: I'm guessing $\left(A \wedge B \wedge C\right) \rightarrow false$ doesn't count, since that would mean $\neg A \vee \neg B \vee \neg C$.

Comment: The issue is: "no negation at all" or "no negation of literals" ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA no negations at all

Answer (score 1):

If we have $\bot$, then it's possible, simply consider $(A\land B\land C)\to\bot\equiv(\lnot A\lor\lnot B\lor\lnot C)$. Otherwise it's not possible. Let $v$ be the valuation function. Consider $v(A)=v(B)=v(C)=\text{T}$. Let $P_i\in\{A,B,C\}$ and $*\in\{\lor,\land,\to\}$, have $v(P_1*P_2)=\text{T}$. Furthermore for any formula that can be expressed in this setting $v(P_1*\dots*P_n)=\text{T}$. However $v(\lnot A\lor \lnot B\lor\lnot C)=\text{F}$, now suppose CNF of $P_1*\dots*P_n$ say $Cl_1\land\dots\land Cl_m$ include $Cl_m:\equiv\lnot A\lor \lnot B\lor\lnot C$, then $$\text{T}=v(P_1*\dots*P_n)= v(Cl_1\land\dots\land Cl_{m-1}\land(\lnot A\lor \lnot B\lor\lnot C))=\text{F}$$
for some clauses $Cl_1\dots Cl_{m-1}$, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: I realize now I copied this answer in my comment, just didn't realize the notation that $\bot$ meant false.

Comment: @Jared good point, with $\bot$, this question seems so obvious.